# No standard output received inside foreach loop

Tags: r, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I'm using `doParallel` to do fairly long parallel processing with `foreach`. Rather than most examples I see, where a computationally-intensive but input-light code is fed into the loop, I'm using `foreach` to coordinate the simultaneous processing of a number of large, independent datasets. So inside the loop, I'm using metadata to read in a file from disk, operate on it, and write back out.

Before I turned this operation into a foreach loop, I was writing out debug messages using `messages()`. However, since I've switched to using `foreach` and `%dopar%`, I've noticed that the loop 'goes dark': it's doing what it ought to, but I'm not receiving any output. (I should mention that this loop is written into a script that I'm calling from the shell with `Rscript`.)

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the fact that `doParallel` spins off other threads—maybe those threads no longer know where to dump standard output? Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not a genius of parallel computing, but it's definitely true that socket-type clusters in R don't return outputs (e.g. progress bars, messages, etc) until the job finishes and returns the output.  I've never worked with fork-type clusters, so I don't know if that would circumvent this limitation or not.  I've been desperate for a progress bar a few times in the past, and there is a work-around when the number of parallel processes is low: write separate, non-parallelized code for each job and run each job by hand in a separate (simultaneous) instance of R.

Comment: @JacobSocolar Oof, that _is_ desperate ;) I ran this non-inreractively via a PBS and found that my logs had error and warning messages from the shell (part of this processing involves using `system()` to call other tools) but not `message()` output in R. So it seems like there's probably it. I suppose another desperate answer is to `system("echo My update")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output from a parallel-foreach loop, just use the option `outfile`: `makeCluster(no_cores, outfile = "/path/to/log_file.txt")`.

Note the the logs of all workers are written to the same file (in the order in which they arrive).

Comment: Will test when I get back from my run, but this sounds like exactly what I need :)

Comment: @ F.Prive: Can you please provide an example as to how you would do this? Thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob Adjust the outfile option to the place of your log file.